# IGraph python get neighbour Vetrices from Vertex

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I have a graph and I want to implement a modification of the Page Rank algorithm. I am stuck on the following point. I don't know how to get all the neighboring vertices from a node.

Currently I am receiving the list of the edges using:

```
g.incident("a", mode="out")
```

This returns me the list of the edges indexes.

How can I get the vertex name from that?

For example I need to know that "a" is linked to "b" and "d"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`g.neighbors("a", mode="out")` will give you the vertex indices for the neighbors. You can then get the names as follows:

```
>>> neis = g.neighbors("a", mode="out")
>>> g.vs[neis]["name"]
```

But actually, if I were you, I would try to work with vertex indices as much as possible because it's way faster to work with the indices than with the names.